# Margin: 0 auto on mobiles always sets margin background-color to element background-color

Tags: android, html, iphone, css, wordpress

It's hard to formulate a brief title. What happens is that the background-color of the centered div extends to the left and right edges of the screen and the background-color of the body is ignored or overridden.

I'm using the twentythirteen theme for this [document](http://test.scoopex.us/wordpress/start/telefon/fast-ankn-cisco-7912/att-ringa/).

It sets a width smaller than the full width and uses margin:0 auto to center the content divs.

In a standard native web view component in our app on Iphone and Android, the automatic margin (left and right) does not become the background-color of the body, but white. Between elements in the content div the correct background-color shows through their margins.

Also, Chrome on Android shows the same white margins.

Have both leading OS developers decided that their respective -kits should do this, or what is going on? Note that the CSS validator throws up hundreds of errors - well, programming a proper theme from scratch is not in the budget for this project.

If you can link to a web page where this works, I could make the web view load that and check.

Comment: It may be that that is the default background color for the webview.  Have you tried changing the webview's background color?

Comment: Tried that now, but it didn't help. I changed the background-color of the centered div, and both in Chrome Mobile and in the app's Web View, it takes that color and extends it out all the way to the display's left and right edges.

Answer (score 0):

A `background-color` is set on several classes.

```
.entry-header, .entry-content, .entry-summary, .entry-meta {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 604px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Delete the `background-color` and the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Yes, that is the centered element. My concern is with the background color of the body around it, in the left and right margins. Simply, I want to set a background color for the body, and some other background-color for some inner elements.

Comment: I also tried to move the auto margin to the outer element, to no avail.

Comment: U can set a background-color on your body, but then you will see two thin lines on the left and right. Is that what you mean? That's because of the boder you set on class .page

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Note that the page has now been changed, and I've accepted this behavior of coloring the automatic margins the same background color as the centered element. The goal of having a slightly less wide mobile web page with the "gutters" in a different color has been abandoned.